# How to draw Venn Diagram on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment, venn-diagram

I have to plot some Venn diagrams to show intersections between arrays of strings. Let me explain: I have a category of names that includes three others that do not intersect each other. I want to understand which of these three occupies the largest percentage of the macro-category mentioned above. I would like to do it with MATLAB but I see that this development environment is somewhat devoid of such functions. If you have any ideas in mind I would be grateful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to plot this, or just calculate percentages? Please provide a sample dataset and the expected output.

Comment: I need a Plot. sample Dataset could be A={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L'} B={'A','B','C','D'} C= {'E','F','G','H','I','L'}

Answer (score 2):

### Venn Diagrams by Plotting Circles

Not the most elegant way but one method of plotting a Venn diagram can be plotting circles and filling the individual circles using a `text()` annotation/label. Unfortunately, here I manually placed where the labels are centred. Automating the label positioning may take several additional steps which I will leave out for simplicity. To find the intersections of the respective datasets I simply used the `intersect()` function.

[image: Venn Diagram Plot]

```
A = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','L'};
B = {'A','B','C','D'};
C = {'E','F','G','H','I','L'};

%Finding the intersections of the arrays%
Intersection_AB = intersect(A,B);
fprintf("Intersection AB: ")
disp(Intersection_AB);
fprintf("\n");

Intersection_BC = intersect(B,C);
fprintf("Intersection BC: ")
disp(Intersection_BC);
fprintf("\n");

Intersection_AC = intersect(A,C);
fprintf("Intersection AC: ")
disp(Intersection_AC);
fprintf("\n");

Intersection_ABC = intersect(Intersection_AB,C);
fprintf("Intersection ABC: ")
disp(Intersection_ABC);
fprintf("\n");
clc;

clf;
Plotting_Interval = 0.01;
Angles_In_Radians = (0: Plotting_Interval: 2*pi);
Circle_Plot = @(X_Offset,Y_Offset,Radius) plot(X_Offset + Radius*cos(Angles_In_Radians),Y_Offset + Radius*sin(Angles_In_Radians));

hold on
%Plotting the 3 circles%
X_Offset_A = 0; Y_Offset_A = 2; Radius_A = 3;
Circle_A = Circle_Plot(X_Offset_A,Y_Offset_A,Radius_A);
fill(Circle_A.XData, Circle_A.YData,'r','FaceAlpha',0.2,'LineWidth',1);

X_Offset_B = -2; Y_Offset_B = -2; Radius_B = 3;
Circle_B = Circle_Plot(X_Offset_B,Y_Offset_B,Radius_B);
fill(Circle_B.XData, Circle_B.YData,'g','FaceAlpha',0.2,'LineWidth',1);

X_Offset_C = 2; Y_Offset_C = -2; Radius_C = 3;
Circle_Plot(X_Offset_C,Y_Offset_C,Radius_C);
Circle_C = Circle_Plot(X_Offset_C,Y_Offset_C,Radius_C);
fill(Circle_C.XData, Circle_C.YData,'b','FaceAlpha',0.2,'LineWidth',1);
title("Venn Diagram");

%Writing all the labels%
A_Label = strjoin(string(A));
text(X_Offset_A,Y_Offset_A,A_Label,'color','r');

B_Label = strjoin(string(B));
text(X_Offset_B,Y_Offset_B,B_Label,'color','g');

C_Label = strjoin(string(C));
text(X_Offset_C,Y_Offset_C,C_Label,'color','b');

AB_Label = strjoin(string(Intersection_AB));
text(-1.2,0,AB_Label);

BC_Label = strjoin(string(Intersection_BC));
text(0,-2,BC_Label);

AC_Label = strjoin(string(Intersection_AC));
text(1.2,0,AC_Label);

ABC_Label = strjoin(string(Intersection_ABC));
text(0,0,ABC_Label);

%Setting the labels to be relative to the centres%
set(findall(gcf,'type','text'),'HorizontalAlignment','center');
axis equal
axis off
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Of great interest! I will try it in the coming days and let you know how it matches with my data!